# Cannot import .ovpn file from Network Manager GUI but using CLI still works

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to import a .ovpn fille in Ubuntu 20.04 using Network Manger GUI. Here's the steps I followed:

1. Go to Network Manager -> Add VPN -> Import a file -> Select .ovpn file
   [Import an ovpn file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUHOE.png)
2. Then this shows up. The "Add" button is blurred so I'm stuck here. I notice that all the generated files (cert, key) are .pem files --> Is this normal?
   [Unable to import. Add button is blurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEB0s.png)

I can still use CLI to connect VPN, and everything works find after that

> sudo openvpn master.ovpn

I can also use CLI to import the .ovpn file

> sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file master.ovpn

[Import via CLI is shown to be successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXsw3.png)

However, the imported VPN doesn't work at all. Turning it on makes me unable to connect to the internet.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the "Add" button grayed out.
I was able to run this from a terminal:

```
sudo nm-connection-editor
```

which brings up the old connection editor. Clicking the + button and choosing "Import from file"  allowed me to import the .ovpn file and make any edits I wanted. After saving it shows up fine in my Network Manager.

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli connection import type openvpn file $file` allows you to import an OpenVPN file, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359923/71928).